# Adding ffmpeg filter to motion image-output

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, motion

I want to be able to apply keystone correction to a webcam stream. The raw image-stream contains a rectangular background and I am using a rectangular overlay, which the user drags the corners to match the actual corners in the image. Finally, the user clicks a button that sends the coordinates to the server. The server then updates the filter parameters and restarts the stream. Everything works using `ffmpeg` to stream RTMP to `nginx`, but the HLS stream generated by `nginx` lags unsatisfactorily and/or hangs. I am using the filter as follows:

```
-lavfi   "perspective=x0=100:y0=20:x1=520:y1=20:x2=100:y2=380:x3=520:y3=380:interpolation=linear:sense=source"
```

Switching to using `motion` to stream the image has much better real-time performance and I can embed the image in the HTML described above absolutely fine. The problem is I can't find a way of inserting the `ffmpeg` filter into the `motion` stream, I think it is only for saved files. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a pointer from the maintainer of `motion`, I have got this working:

1. Install the `v4l2loopback` device. In my case, it reported the loopback device as `/dev/video2`, so the `ffmpeg` command streams from the webcam on `/dev/video0` through the perspective filter, correcting the keystone effect, and puts the result to `/dev/video2`.

```bsh
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2 -lavfi \
     "perspective=x0=23:y0=43:x1=500:y1=38:x2=33:y2=467:x3=508:y3=471:interpolation=linear:sense=source"
```

2. Run `motion` as standard, but using the loopback device as the camera input.

Still a bit to do to make the `ffmpeg` re-start nicely, but it is mostly there now.